Reference request: finite field computation over the Word-RAM model
Let $q  = p^\ell$ be a positive integer power of a prime $p$, of size  $q = \text{poly}(n)$.
Over the Word-RAM model (with words of size $O(\log n)$), how quickly can we perform addition and multiplication over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$? In particular, can addition and multiplication be done in $O(1)$ time over the Word-RAM model? If this is not possible for general $q$, is it possible when $q = 2^\ell$ is a power of two? Is there a standard reference for the complexity of these operations?
For concreteness, in this question, assume we already have access to a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $\ell$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, so that $\mathbb{F}_q \cong \mathbb{F}_p / \langle f\rangle$.

I don't know if this is the latest, but in the circuit model https://doi.org/10.1007/s10958-013-1350-5 gives a nice overview (from 2013).

Looks like Lemma 2.6 from https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.20326 answers my question. Constant time addition and multiplication are possible over $\mathbb{F}_q$ in the Word-RAM model, provided you first spend some $O(q^\varepsilon)$ preprocessing time, for some arbitrarily small constant $\varepsilon > 0$ (and this preprocessing is not necessary if $q = p$ is a prime).
